# Where can I find the FlexMonkium source code?

Tags: apache-flex, automated-tests

Does anyone know where I can get a hold of the FlexMonkium source code? I can checkout the FlexMonkey source but I cannot seem to locate the FlexMonkium source.

Comment: Did you ask on the Flex Monkey Forums? http://www.gorillalogic.com/forum/7

Comment: Yes I did. And I got a response from them. http://www.gorillalogic.com/forumpost/1038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the source is included in FlexMonkey 4.1,

https://svn.gorillalogic.com/svn/flexmonkey/tags/4.1

Use your User name (not email address) and password from the GorillaLogic website to login.

**Note:** You shouldn't have to modify the FlexMonkey source for things like custom components. You can do that simply by creating a new automation delegate.